# torrent client with multi-trackers support (not command-line)

Tags: 12.10, bittorrent

I'm looking for a torrent client that supports multi-trackers like utorrent does.
I'm trying qbittorent, I open a magnet link with it and it works ok but if I add more magnet links from other trackers it does not add those trackers to the previous ones, I always have to do it by myself doing "add new tracker" and copying the udp link.
I'm also not sure that it's using all the trackers I added.

Is there any graphic program like utorrent that handles multi-trackers?

Thanks

Comment: Tried transmission?

Comment: I was sure I red that it does not support multi-trackers, but I will try now thanks